# Codeigniter PHP MVC confusion (New CI kid on the block)

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-3

This is my first time working with Codeigniter and need some help please.
I need to do a Db lookup with JOINS & WHERE statements following the CI 3 tutorial and web resources but ran solid into a wall and am not 100% sure where & what I am doing wrong...

My Categorylis_model.php looks as follow:
        class Categorylist_model extends CI_Model {

```
    public function __construct()
    {
            $this->load->database();
    }
    public function get_categoryads()
    {

       $this->db->select('ads.id AS id, ad_image.image AS image, ads.userid AS userid, ads.adnr AS adnr,
      ads.location AS town, search_town.townFileName AS townlink, search_prov.provLabel AS province, 
      search_prov.subLink AS provlink,text,
      adcat.name AS catname,  adcat.clinkname AS clinkname, adsubcat.name AS subcatname, adsubcat.linkname AS subcatlink,
      adcat.id AS catid, adsubcat.id AS subcatid, ads.r_option AS r_option, ads.R_rand AS R_rand, 
      adcat.catcol1 AS catcol1, adcat.catcol2 AS catcol2, search_town.townId,ads.townId');
      $this->db->from('ads');
      $this->db->join('adsubcat', 'adsubcat.id=ads.subcatid');
      $this->db->join('adcat', 'adcat.id=ads.catid');
      $this->db->join('search_town', 'search_town.townId=ads.townId');
      $this->db->join('search_region', 'search_region.regionId=search_town.relRegionId');
      $this->db->join('search_prov', 'search_prov.provId=search_region.relProvId');
      $this->db->join('ad_image', 'ad_image.adid=ads.id');
      $this->db->where("adcat.id='2' AND ads.subcatid!='843' AND scam=0 AND adactive=1 AND ads.userid=ad_image.user AND 
      ad_image.picorder=1 AND ad_image.aproved =1 AND ads.subcatid !='843' AND ads.subcatid !='841'");
      $this->db->group_by("ads.userid");
      $this->db->order_by('addate','desc');
      $this->db->limit(10); 
      return $query->row_array();
    }

    }
```

The Categories.php controller looks as follow:

```
  defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

  class Categories extends CI_Controller 
  {
      public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('categorylist_model');
    }
    public function index()
     {
          $this->load->helper('url');
          $data = array('sitename'=>'CategoryAds', 'page_title' => 'Categories');
      $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
          $this->load->view('templates/navbar');
          $this->load->view('templates/breadcrumbs');
          //$this->load->view('templates/category_selector');
          $this->load->view('content_categories');
          $this->load->view('templates/footer');


     }
    public function view()
    {
      $data['categories'] = $this->categorieslist_model->get_categoryads();
    }

  }
```

My view then has the following:

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $ad_item): ?>
 <?php echo $ad_item['text'] ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

When looking at the page I get the following error.

```
        A PHP Error was encountered
    Severity: Notice
    Message: Undefined variable: categories

    Filename: views/content_categories.php
    Line Number: 114

    Backtrace:
    File: /usr/www/XXXXXXX/ci/application/views/content_categories.php
    Line: 114
    Function: _error_handler

    File: /usr/www/XXXXXXX/ci/application/controllers/Categories.php
    Line: 18
    Function: view

    File: /usr/www/XXXXXXX/ci/index.php
    Line: 292
    Function: require_once
```

Comment: How do you load your view "content_cagetory" ?

Comment: My apologies (Might be a stupid question...)... What do you mean How do I load it?

Comment: Welcome to SO and to CI. What is the URL you are entering to load your page? to me, it seems that you are using `localhost/yourapp/index.php/categories/index` which means you are not loading your model, nor sending the right data to your view

Comment: If you are still around, I will be able to help you remotely for any CI questions you may have.

Comment: @CodeGodie I am still deep in it ;-)
The URL i use is http://www.domain/ci/index.php/categories

Comment: right.. thats why you are getting those errors. Do you want me to help you through Teamviewer so I can walk you though it as well?

Comment: awesome.. and what is the passcode?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller would be as follows -

```
public function index() {
          $this->load->helper('url');
          $data['metadata'] = array('sitename'=>'CategoryAds', 'page_title' => 'Categories');
//directly
$data['categories'] = $this->categorylist_model->get_categoryads();

          $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
          $this->load->view('templates/navbar');
          $this->load->view('templates/breadcrumbs');
          $this->load->view('content_categories', $data);
          $this->load->view('templates/footer');


     }
    /** No need I think
   public function view() {
      $data['categories'] = $this->categorieslist_model->get_categoryads();
    } **/
```

Your view would be - `content_categories.php`

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $ad_item): ?>
<?php echo $ad_item['text'] ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

My Process of work with Codeigniter is as follows-

Cat_model.php in model directory

```
public function get_category() {
// active records code with return
}
```

CatCon.php in controller directory

```
function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('cat_model');
}
function index() {
   $data['categories'] = $this->cat_model->get_category();
   // pass the data variable to view
   $this->load->view('content_categories', $data);
}
```

content_categories.php in view directory

```
print_r($categories);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I now get the following errors:

A PHP Error was encountered
Message: Undefined variable: query
Filename: models/Categorylist_model.php
Line Number: 29
File: /usr/www/ci/application/controllers/Categories.php
Line: 15
Function: get_categoryads

Comment: if you still get the same error then recheck your code. follow mine process i showed

Comment: I replaced my code with your suggestion @samrat-khan

Answer (score 0):

glad I was able to help. Like I said, a couple of problems but with time, they will be very easy to notice.

- one, the controller wasnt being called properly.
- the database query was not returning the right data

Comment: Still too much of a newby in SO, but will revisit this page again to votr you up once I qualify :-)